# Make image appear/disappear when clicked

Tags: excel, vba

Let's say I draw a rectangle and then I insert a picture and put it on rectangle. What I want to do now is when I click on the picture with the mouse it disappears and all I can see is the rectangle, but when I click on the rectangle, the same image appears again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code can be reused for multiple pictures/rectangles. The trick is that the rectangle has to be named after the respective picture with prefixing rect_, for example my picture is called 'Picture 1' and the respective rectangle to be renamed as 'rect_Picture 1' and place 'Picture 1' on it. Assign the below code to both the objects.

```
Sub TogglePictureVisibilty()
    Dim picName As String

    'Capture the macro calling object name
    picName = Application.Caller

    'Remove rect_ from object name if exists
    If Left(picName, 5) = "rect_" Then
            picName = Mid(picName, 6, Len(picName))
    End If

    'Hide if visible and vice versa
    ActiveSheet.Shapes(picName).Visible = Not ActiveSheet.Shapes(picName).Visible
End Sub
```

Hope this helps.